# Python IDLE Autocomplete and Call Tips No Longer Pop Up

Tags: python, tkinter, osx-yosemite, python-idle, activetcl

I recently upgraded to **Python 2.7.10** on **MacOSX Yosemite**. I also added a **Python 3.4.3** installation. At the time I upgraded **Tcl/Tk** with **ActiveTcl 8.5.18** as was suggested on the Python for MacOSX installation page. There is also an **ActiveTcl 8.6** package from last year that still shows up in the framework, but I was pretty sure that I said to delete that when I went back to an earlier version of 8.5. Path has settings for all three as well as usr/bin, etc.

At this point, **Autocomplete** and **Call Tips** stopped popping up. I checked the preferences and it seemed to be turned on. The delay was set to `2000`, so I changed that to `2`, but nothing happened. Pressing **{ctrl}-Spacebar** and then using the down arrow key lets me cycle through the the available functions, but putting a dot after an object has no effect, and if I open parentheses, I get no tips. This is both in the **IDLE Shell** and **Editor** windows.

I tried to redo everything by deleting all instances of Python from my drive. I reinstalled them, reloaded all packages, and Autocomplete and **Call Tips** still are not popping up. Is there any known issues or is there a workaround? Do I possibly need to add or change the new **Tk path** somewhere so that **IDLE** can find what it needs to popup autocomplete? Is there a way that I can initiate **IDLE Autocomplete** and **Call Tips** during the coding session to manually get them to work?

I have also raised this with **ActiveState** and **Python**, but I haven't gotten or found an answer yet that has gotten it to work. I like working with **IDLE** and would like to get **Autocomplete** and **Call Tips** up and running again.

Thank you.

Comment: **Update** I decided to completely uninstall Tcl/Tk 8.5.18 and 8.6 from my system. This reverted everything back to Apple's 8.5.9, which makes IDLE unstable. However doing this allowed Autocomplete and Call Tips to work again. I downloaded a new .dmg and reinstalled 8.5.18 and Autocomplete and Call Tips stopped working. It appears that the problem lies with ActiveTcl 8.5.18 for Mac. Does anyone know how to invoke Autocomplete and Call Tips from IDLE manually, or if there is a setting change that can make it work, like importing a TK module?

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue24570 on the CPython tracker.

Comment: One and the same... Trying to cover all my bases. :-)